# JAVA - Newbie trying to get user input

Tags: java

I am an extreme beginner in Java and I can't seem to get the user input. I am using eclipse mars. My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    Scanner UserName = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(UserName);   

}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to first create your `Scanner`, then call [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) on it to get input from the user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class NameAsker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        String userName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name is: " + userName);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
System.out.println(UserName.nextLine());
```

Read [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) for more info

Answer (score 0):

you can use like.

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
```

if you want to get integer.

```
int number=input.nextInt();
System.out.Println(number);
```

for String:

```
String str=input.nextLine();
```

There are other method for taking user input like `bufferedReader` and BufferedInputStream for more details  check Java Docs.